# ASP.NET dropdownlist selectedindex change firing for programmatic selection changes

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have asp.net page with dynamic dropdown controls and I need only the `selectedIndexchanged` event to fire only for the user selection.

At present `selectedIndexchanged` event is firing for each programatically selection changes.

Can some one suggest how to check/fire the `selectedIndexchanged` event only the "User" selection?

Comment: you have to create an eventhandler for you control

Comment: are you adding items to dropdown one by one?

Comment: Yes I am adding one by one. but the event should fire only for the user selection. Based on the user selection I am adjusting the other dropdown values programmatically so now it fires for even programmatic selection changes as well. Can some one suggest how to get only the selectedindexchanged only for the user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this work for you

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs  e){

    DropDownList cbTest = new DropDownList();
    cbTest.ID = "cbot";
    //create an event handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event
    cbTest.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cbt_SelectedIndexChanged);        
    cbTest.Items.Add("1");
    cbTest.Items.Add("2");
    cbTest.Items.Add("3");
    //set the AutoPostBack property to sends the data back to the server
    cbTest.AutoPostBack = true;
    this.form1.Controls.Add(cbTest);

}
//handle the selections made by the User
void cbt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("This works");
}
```

Comment: Actually I am following the same code and I need to change the other dropdown values based on user selection 

e.g I have 5 dropdown with values 1 to 5 selected and if used selected the first dropdown values to 5 then I need to change the other selected values programmatically.

So what I need is, selectedindexchanged event fire only for the **user selection** and it should not fire the event for the programmatic selection changes.